# Issue with coloring along with the cells that can grow in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Below is the screen shot of the issue[image]

The first field (work process name) will grow , rest of the fields are always in the same way. Other fields(except the first) have colors depending on some conditions. 
The issue is, when first field grows , the color in the other fields do not cover the height, it shows white as in below image. (before the black line ,we can see white gap after the yellow color). It just colors single cell height .How to extend the colors as per the height of first field.

Answer (score 0):

Since the colored fields can't grow, they will not fill the extra space. You will need to enable the "can Grow" property in those fields as well since the whole row gets bigger if the first field increases in size. The other fields need to grow as well to make up the extra space.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try growing all the fields there.